# Css negative z-index does not work inside another element

Tags: css, hover, element, z-index

I have a link and when I hover, it will get a background.

Directly in the body I can set `-1` on the `:before` to keep it behind the text. Inside elements which have a background this is not possible because `-1` is not set behind the current element but behind all the elements.

So what can I do to fix it?

- I have a 100 links in different elements so I prefer not to add additional HTML around them.
- In real life it's not just a background, it's an animation, therefor the need of `:before`.
- I prefer CSS solutions over javascript solutions.

In the example below, when hover the first link, it will get a background color. When hover the second link inside the element, it will not get a background color. Exepected result is to have a background color to the link inside the element as well, on hover.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link</a>

<div class="block">
  <a href="#">Link in block</a>
</div>
```

Comment: just add  .block a {z-index:2}. If i understand your question

Comment: always set a z-index to the relative parent element (even 0)

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do things this way at all, but . . . just change your css to a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}